# How to overwrite url from window.location.href

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url-rewriting, window.location

I want to show an image and its metadatas by using this kind of url in a browser:

```
domain/image/imageName
```

but the actual script to get the image link based on its name is called in:

```
domain/image.html
```

I've made this RewriteRule in my htAccess file :

```
RewriteRule ^image\/(\w+)$ image.html?$1 [NC]
```

To transforme my "fake" url like this :

```
domain/image/imageName => domain/image.html?$1
```

In order to get the image name, I used the window.location.href to see what I've got and my console show me this :

```
Url = http://localhost/image/ImageName
//and not//
Url = http://localhost/image.html?ImageName
//as I expected
```

Do someone know how to get what htaccess actually transform or suggest a better method ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your `/image.html?ImageName` URL is only an internal rewrite on the server side, the client knows nothing about it - so client-side JavaScript can not access _that_ URL in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Question answered in comment. I also found a regex way to extract what I got from the js function :

```
window.location.href.match("[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+[^\/]$")
```